# Problem formatting date using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following date:

```
2011-09-09T18:01:47Z
```

I want it to appear as

`"9/9/11 at 1:47PM"` whatever the correct time is

This code returns a null string:

```
NSLog(@"TIME: %@",[message valueForKey:@"created_at"]);
    NSString* time = [message valueForKey:@"created_at"];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy at HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* newTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:time];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy at HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString* finalTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newTime];
```

Comment: im not sure what you mean? i posted the original input time, and what i expect for output in my question. let me know and i can update the question more.

Comment: I don't think your first date has a right format to be formatted, I mean the "2011-09-09T18:01:47Z" date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formatting is the same for both and they have little to no relation to your input and  your output. Refer to the [Unicode Data Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) whenever you have issues.

```
NSString *datein = @"2011-09-09T18:01:47Z";

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//The Z at the end of your string represents Zulu which is UTC
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate* newTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datein];

//Add the following line to display the time in the local time zone
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy 'at' h:mma"];
NSString* finalTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newTime];
NSLog(@"%@", finalTime);
```