# NSDate with NSDateFormatter returns nil date

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I want to convert a string to an NSDate, like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSDate *createdAt = [dateFormat dateFromString:[value valueForKey:@"created_at"]];
```

When I log createdAt it returns nil for some reason and I can't figure out why.

```
[value valueForKey:@"created_at"]];
Returns a NSCFString that looks like this:
2013-05-15T05:55:57Z
```

I have no idea why it's nil, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure [value valueForKey] isn't nil?

Comment: what does it look like? Perhaps the parser really can't parse it

Comment: You will have to set `[dateFormat setDateFormat:...]` with the correct format for your string, there are a lot of questions and answers about that at SO. - But you have tagged this "core-data", so if `value` is a Core Data object then you should store a date attribute instead of a string.

Comment: Hi and thanks @MartinR, do you have a suggestion on how the date format should look for the string `2013-05-15T05:55:57Z`? :)

Comment: so you want a date to a string not a string to a date?

Comment: The first part of this answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7365979/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR If you want then you can add it as an answer, and I will check it as correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem formatting date using NSDateFormatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365817/problem-formatting-date-using-nsdateformatter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set date format to the `NSDateFormatter` first. This should be working:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *createdAt = [dateFormat dateFromString:[value valueForKey:@"created_at"]];
```

However I'm not sure about your input date string. The last letter `Z` should be identification of date's time zone. Letter `Z` is the format specifier for the time zone according to `Unicode Date Format Patterns` (http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).